# operator overloading in c# with virtual

Tags: c#, asp.net, overloading, virtual, operator-keyword

**how can i do same thing with virtual keyword in operator overloading ==

### how to achive same thing as in main method with virtual keyword

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Base
    {
        protected int x_value = 0;    

        public Base(int x)
        {
            x_value = x;
        }

        public static bool operator==(Base b1, Base b2)
        {
            if( object.ReferenceEquals( b1, b2 ) )
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if( object.ReferenceEquals( b1, null ) || 
                     object.ReferenceEquals( b2, null ) )
            {
                return false;
            }

            return b1.Equals(b2);            
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Base b1, Base b2)
        {
            return !(b1 == b2);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if( obj == null )
                return false;

            Base o = obj as Base;

            if( o != null )    
                return x_value == o.x_value;
            return false;
        }


        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return x_value.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    class Derived : Base
    {
        protected int y_value = 0;


        public Derived(int x, int y) : base(x)
        {
            y_value = y;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if( !base.Equals( obj ) )
              return false; 

            Derived o = obj as Derived;

            if( o == null )
                return false;

            return y_value == o.y_value;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return x_value.GetHashCode() ^ y_value.GetHashCode() + x_value;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Base b1 = new Derived(10, 12);
            Base b2 = new Derived(10, 11);

            Console.WriteLine(b1 == b2);

            b2 = null;

            Console.WriteLine(b1 == b2);

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I want the two objects b1 and b2 in the Program class to call operator overloading to derived class

Answer (score 3):

That's not possible as operators cannot be `virtual` in C#.

To achieve what you want, I suggest to do the comparison in `Equals` (which is `virtual` and can be overridden) and let the operator only call `Equals`:

```
public class Base
{
   //... shortened for brevity

   public static bool operator==(Base b1, Base b2)
   {
       return ReferenceEquals(b1, null) ? ReferenceEquals(b2, null) : b1.Equals(b2);
   }

   public override bool Equals(object obj)
   {
        Base o = obj as Base;
        if (o == null) return false;
        return x_value == o.x_value;
   }    
}
```

And the derived:

```
public class Derived : Base
{
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if(!base.Equals( obj ) )
          return false; 

        Derived o = obj as Derived;
        if( o == null ) return false;
        return y_value == o.y_value;
    }
}
```

Now always the correct `Equals` method is used.

**NOTE**: Don't use `if (obj == null)` in your `Base.Equals()` method! This will lead to a `StackOverflowException` as you call the `==` operator again which in turn calls `Equals` again. Always use `ReferenceEquals()` to check for `null` in those operators and `Equals` methods.

Comment: @karanvyas not that I can think of. what's wrong with this method? as I said, operators cannot be virtual in C#.

Comment: but in my program i can not use that Equals method. i have to  override ==

Comment: @karanvyas overriding `==` is not possible. But you can of course use another virtual method instead of `Equals`. But it really sounds like a design flaw to have an `==` operator that behaves different than `Equals`.